# Reproducing Smoothing from Generalizer Plugin in v.generalizer in QGIS Processing Toolbar

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-2, generalization, smoothing

I´d like to reproduce the smoothing operations done with the Generalizer Plugin inside the `v.generalizer` Toolbox so I can use them on a polygon layer instead of only on a line layer.

I tried different values for different settings but I just don't see how to get the same results using the v.generalizer algorithm in the Processing toolbar.

To which values in the `v.generalizer` algorithm window do the settings I see in the generalizer plugin correspond to?

Here are the settings I´d like to use and the results I get:

1. Hermite

   [image]
2. Chaikin

   [image]

Now in the `v.generalize` windows, there are so many options and values but nothing there is named the same as the ones in the generalizer plugin…

I tried using the v.generalizer toolbox after reading these two questions:

- [Is there a QGIS bezier curve tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95225/is-there-a-qgis-bezier-curve-tool)
- [Is there a way to render lines with a smooth (bezier) curves in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18768/is-there-a-way-to-render-lines-with-a-smooth-bezier-curves-in-qgis)

I'm using QGIS 2.4.

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference in wording, but I think the options from the **Generalizer** plugin exists in the **v.generalizer** interface. Using *Google Translate* (yes, not the best thing to use) for the Generalizer [Homepage](http://www.gis-support.pl/generalizer/), we can find a description on each algorithms used and their corresponding parameters.

---

In terms of **Hermite Spline Interpolation**, the homepage tells us:

```
Threshold - Determines the distance between the created points.

Thightness - Factor determining the degree of bending of the resulting line.
```

Now looking at the *Help* section in **v.generalizer**, we can try and find those parameters mentioned above. For *Threshold*:

```
threshold=float
Maximal tolerance value <------ This is in the options.
Options: 0-1000000000
```

For *Thightness*:

```
Minimum angle between two consecutive segments in Hermite method <--- This is in the options.
```

[image: Hermite]

---

In terms of **Chaiken's Algorithm**, the homepage tells us:

```
Level - Determines the number of iterations of the algorithm.

Weight - Determines the shear rate, the bigger the fillets are closer to the line of nodes.
```

Now we look at the *Help* section in **v.generalizer** again. For *Level*:

```
Number of iterations <----- This is in the options.
```

For *Weight*:

```
betweeness_thresh - It denotes to what extent a line is in between the other lines in the network (unsure if this is the correct parameter!)
```

[image: Chaiken]