# Smoothen Line vector QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, smoothing

I am working on a publication and would like to make my schematic visually pleasing. The amount of detail is too high and the image would be better If I could simplify and smooth my line and polygon vectors. Ideally it would minic smooth Bezier like curves. (Curves are not yet supported in QGIS so searching an alternative)

I've tried many many settings in QGIS, primarily the v.generalize tool but I either get errors or the results still has sharp corners.

[image]

A close up reveals the ugly sharp corners of the vectors. 
[image]

And I would like to get something like this:
[image]

Is there a simple way to simplify the vectors into smooth lines? Alternativily, which settings in GRASS v.generalize should I use?

Related question: [Is there a way to render lines with a smooth (bezier) curves in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18768/is-there-a-way-to-render-lines-with-a-smooth-bezier-curves-in-qgis)

It seems like v.generalize with Chaiken algorithm could do the trick. Searching for the correct settings. (Trial and error)

Shapefiles can be found [here](https://onewri-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/rutger_hofste_wri_org/Ecop05IxHFxFsUyGrn6OJckBfnfQudnVva7hf8maUYmokg?e=aaN2dH)

Comment: Have you checked several plugins, namely [SmoothLine](https://gitlab.com/albertodeluca/smooth_line) and [Cartographic Line Generalization](https://github.com/geof-osgl/CartoLineGen)?

Comment: QGis 3.4 has the tool "smoothgeometry" in the toolbox. This might be what you're looking for.

Comment: the build-in smooth function doesn't result in the desired output. I've tried multiple offset and angle settings.

Comment: Cartographic Line generalization just transposes my shapefile. Very odd.

Comment: Specify 1) would you like to smooth only hydrographic lines or even polygons? 2) or Do you only need a processing tool in QGIS?

Comment: look at 2 options of hydrography of soft and rough force, maybe they will suit you...https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o5Hz_toFHBCFMoZiD2Wt6QfUuNizu7_c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is usually a two step process: simplify the lines first to remove the unwanted detail, and then smooth the result

Comment: @Cyril the result you obtained is a step in the right direction. Both versions still have sharp vertices though. The desired result is one without any sharp corners (exceptions at bifurcations). I think some pre-processing is required. I.e. merge each branch into a single line and simplify before smoothing.

Comment: I believe it is difficult to do this in automated mode, and perhaps better after an automated way to Refine the hydrographic elements for manual visualization...

Comment: agreed. It would be cool if QGIS allowed to export a smooth, simplified version of the map for  schematics in documents.

Answer (score 21):

You can use a geometry generator in styling as symbol layer style and smooth function. The advantage of this solution is that the geometry is intact.

Smooth 0: 
[image: Geomoetry Generator - Smooth 0]

Smooth 5:
[image: Geomoetry Generator - Smooth 5]

Comment: this looks promising. The only issue is that my shapefile consists of multilines (I've added a download link). At each end of a single line, the corner remains sharp. I will probably have to merge/dissolve to get the result I want.

Comment: Is there a way to save/export the smooth(ed?) geometry as a new vector file?

Comment: @BERA in processing you will find generate geometry algorytm.

Comment: It doesn't give very nice results for closed loops at the vertex where the loop closes. Is there anyway to improve this?